# How to step over a linearized 2D-array with a moving window

Tags: arrays, indexing

Assuming I have a 4x4 array that's flatted out in row-major order and I want to collect one entry per 2x2 window in a new 1D array, that would result in:

[0, 2, 8, 10]

for 4x8 it would result in
[0, 2, 4, 6, 16, 18, 20, 22]

and for 8x4 it would result in
[0, 2, 8, 10, 16, 18, 24, 26]

simple loop for achieving this:

```
const int STEP = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  arr[i] =  i * STEP + (i*STEP / SIZE_Y) * SIZE_Y;
```

I run into problems when the array size is odd on either dimension though.
3x3 should result in

[0, 2, 6, 8] but does in [0, 2, 7, 12]

How do I have to extend my formula so it doesn't get overly complicated treating all these boundary-cases but still works for the general case?

Comment: SIZE_X and SIZE_Y are the dimensions of the original array. Even though it's flatted out in memory, this must be known because otherwise the representation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used nested loops and it worked perfectly, and it's much easier to understand:

```
    int width, height;
    width = (int) ceil((double)SIZE_Y/STEP);
    height = (int) ceil((double)SIZE_X/STEP);
    int[] arr = new int[width*height];
    for(int i=0; i < height; i ++){
        for(int j=0; j < width; j ++){
            arr[i*width+j] = STEP*i*SIZE_Y + STEP*j;
        }
    }
```

However if you still insist on using a single loop -less readable- you can use this single loop instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<width*height; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (i%width)*STEP + (i/width)*SIZE_Y*STEP;
    }
```

Comment: yup, works, thank you. I apparently was too blinded to consider nested loops. :)